# Why is pop_back() not working in this code?

Tags: c++, vector

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <pair<int,int>> s1= {{1,2}, {2,3}, {4,5}, {5,6}};
    int x= 10, count; 
    while (!s1.empty() && s1.back().first <= x )
    {
        count= count + s1.back().second;
        if (s1.back().first== x && s1.back().second== -1)
        {
            ++count; 
        }
        s1.pop_back();
    }
    for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        cout << s1[i].first << " " << s1[i].second << endl;
    }
}
```

When I run this program, it outputs all the elements originally in the vector `s1`. Shouldn't the vector be empty due to the use of `pop_back()`?

Comment: In an empty vector *all* indexes (even `0`) will be out of bounds. If you use out of bounds indexes you have undefined behavior. End of story, really.

Comment: you assume that the vector has 4 elements, try to use `s1.size()` instead

Comment: You have undefined behavior (uninitialized `count`, accessing 4 elements of array). The program can do whatever it wants to, including returning the "ghosts" of deleted array elements.

Answer (score 2):

`while (!s1.empty() && s1.back().first <= x )`

Logically equates to this:

```
 while (!s1.empty())
```

Because all the `first` elements in the vector are smaller than 10, which means the `while` terminates only when the vector is empty.

Then, in the `for` loop, you access out of bounds, causing undefined behavior.

Simply change the `for` loop to this:

```
 for (int i=0; i<s1.size(); ++i)
 {
     cout << s1[i].first << " " << s1[i].second << endl;
 }
```

You could also use [`std::for_each()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) from the [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) header:

```
std::for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), [](auto const &it) {
    cout << it.first << " " << it.second << endl;
});
```

Comment: I got the feeling that the OP was shocked that they could still view the items even though the vector was empty / did not understand why the program did not crash or complain about this.

Comment: @drescherjm every c\c++ programmer experiences an undefined behavior at some point :)

Comment: @Bhavika maybe you should ask a new question about your code and what you wanted it to do. This question is really about the undefined behavior of accessing elements of an empty vector it is both answered and closed as a duplicate. I can tell you that I don't understand exactly what you wanted with your code.

Comment: A [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) would be better: `for(auto &it : s1) { cout << it.first << " " << it.second << endl; };`